# Stub a template in a controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Hi I'm working on a project, and I need to test the ability of my controller to switch which views it renders depending on certain conditions.

The best way for me to do this would be to use the stub_template method. However this seems to only work in view specs. Is there an equivalent I can use in the controller specs? or a way for me to be able to use the method outside of a view spec?

Comment: Why would you need the `stub_template` method? For what you have explained you just want to check if the controller is going to render the right view, right?

Comment: Wouldn't this be enough? http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.5/classes/ActionController/TemplateAssertions.html#method-i-assert_template